# R or Python, Is it possible to get the necessary sample size in a proportions power test calculation with ratio of sample sizes fixed?

Tags: python, r, testing

Given two proportions, `p1 and p2`,

I want to calculate the necessary samples of p1 I would need to do a Z-test of equivalence if:

```
1) alpha = .05
2) power = 0.9
3) n1/n2 = r
```

The Python stats models program gives something like this, but I think it is wrong because it gets drastically different answers from the STATA sampsi program.

The stata code is:

```
sampsi .01 .1, alpha(0.05) ratio(2)
```

which gives

```
Estimated sample size for two-sample comparison o
```

> f proportions

Test Ho: p1 = p2, where p1 is the proportion in p

> opulation 1
>                       and p2 is the proportion in p
>   opulation 2
>   Assumptions:

```
     alpha =   0.0500  (two-sided)
     power =   0.9000
        p1 =   0.0100
        p2 =   0.1000
     n2/n1 =   2.00
```

Estimated required sample sizes:

```
        n1 =      119
        n2 =      238
```

The python code is:

```
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
es = sms.proportion_effectsize(0.01, 0.1)
sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(es, power=0.9, alpha=0.05, ratio=2)
```

Which gives:

```
80.25164112946563
```

Comment: Could you share the Python code you tried vs STATA answer? Maybe someone can figure out why they're different.

Comment: `Hmisc::bsamsize` google better

Comment: @Rawr, that package doesn't seem to do part (3) of my request.

Comment: I've been wondering about a very similar problem too.

Comment: @robbieboy74 it does. Reading the help file gives it away basically.

Comment: @Joris, sorry, I just missed it (Long night!), thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rawr says in comments above, `bsamsize` works (you need to set the `frac` argument to the fraction of samples in group 1)

```
library("Hmisc")
bsamsize(.01, .1, power=.9, frac=1/3)
      n1       n2 
102.8526 205.7051
```

These are not the same numbers as Stata gives, but they're close. `?bsamsize` gives details of the algorithm used.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check rule of thumb sample size for proportion comparisons (though it is for equal groups), given by following formula:

```
N = 16 * p * (1-p) / (d**2)
```

where probability `p = 0.1` and

difference `d = p1 - p2 = 0.1 - 0.01 = 0.09`

N comes to 178 for each group (356 in total) with your values, which is virtually same as total size given by Stata (357).

One reference for above formula is: https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-run-an-ab-test.html